# pass an array of Ids back from a view to a rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form in which people can select a date, and click "filter". This date is then passed back to the controller as a parameter, and the view is reloaded with a list of users named @users

I then have a form that I want to pass the @users back as an array

I tried this

```
  = form_tag('/complete_export', :method => "put", :id => 'export') do |f|
    %p=hidden_field_tag "users", "#{@users.map(&:id)}"
    %p=submit_tag("Export results »")
```

But when it gets back to the controller, the parameter arrives back looking like this...

```
[8] pry(#<AccountsController>)> params[:users]
"[53533, 51780, 17418, 153, 50667, 141, 48968, 48343, 48338, 47377, 44736, 40410, 27878, 172, 150, 34457, 37757, 26715, 31240, 31178, 30016, 184, 177, 196, 193, 155, 170]"
```

so it's actually coming back as a string. How do I pass it to the controller as an array, or change it in the controller into an array.

EDIT

So I have now amended my form as such...

```
  = form_tag('/complete_export', :method => "get", :id => 'export') do |f|
    - @users.each do |user|
      =hidden_field_tag :user_ids, :multiple => true, :value => user.id
    %p=submit_tag("Export results »")
```

Back in the controller, the params are showing as...

```
        "utf8" => "✓",
"employee_ids" => "{:multiple=>true, :value=>170}",
      "commit" => "Export results »",
      "action" => "complete_payrite_export",
  "controller" => "accounts"
```

clearly I'm missing something :(

Comment: What you were missing is that you misread my answer. You are using the ```_tag``` sufix, and that doesn't allow you to pass the ```multiple``` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using `hidden_field_tag` with `f.hidden_field` arguments, here is `hidden_field_tag` alternative:

```
- @users.each do |user|
  = hidden_field_tag 'user_ids[]', user.id
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `multiple` option, which in my opinion is cleaner than doing a casting in the controller.

```
- @users.each do |user|
  = f.hidden_field :user_ids, :multiple => true, :value => user.id
```

You will get an array named `user_ids` in your controller.

Comment: see my edit: I'm actually getting "employee_ids" => "{:multiple=>true, :value=>170}",

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is that you are using the ```_tag``` suffix.